# How to convert Raster to points in MapInfo?

Tags: raster, vector, mapinfo

**I wanted to convert Raster data to point data in MapInfo.Does there any tool to convert? can anyone help me?**

Comment: What format is your raster data?

Comment: i have to convert 30 M ASTER DEM data

Comment: In your title, you ask about converting to polygon, but in the body, you ask about converting to point.  Which one are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Mapinfo 16 then you can easily convert raster data to point data.

Just open Mapinfo and go to Raster->Raster Operations->Export.

In the tool that comes up, select input Raster. In export to option, select Mapinfo TAB.

Select all other relevant option and run the operation.
After sometimes you will get the desired result.

[image]